# external CSS sheet not loading to hosting

Tags: css, hosting, stylesheet, cpanel

I'm having trouble making my CSS external stylesheet work in my actual hosting. It all works fine when I open the files from my Finder (I'm using a mac), but the stylesheet does not seem to load to my server properly. All other html files load fine and are visible when you visit my website in any browser,[this is my website](http://www.socialadventuring.com) and the File Manager on my cPanel indicates that the CSS folder and external stylesheet file have been successfully uploaded for enough time that the style features should display. I tried clearing my browsing history and reopening my browser.

My link tag is  and I have tried it using  aswell as with just "css/socialpolarities.css". I've checked to make sure the spelling is right on the path and corresponds to the actual file.

Is the answer to just put all the style files in the public_html folder and then just change the path on all my html files? Or am I missing something?

I'm also using LiquidWeb if that means anything

Comment: please make css folder in public_html folder and put all styles file in css folder  and then try it

Comment: That already exists, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The file css/socialpolarities.css seems to exist, but is void of content.
try looking at your local file to make sure it is indeed the one with the css code, then upload it to the same folder and override the original one. 
You may have had an upload error.

Comment: Right? It's really strange. I tried overwriting the css file in my FTP client and also tried deleting and uploading it again in the cPanel, no dice on either. The CSS file is definitely the right one too. Also tried deleting my history and opening my browser again with the changes.

Comment: I thought that I may have a problem with my <link> tags that link to my stylesheet, I tried to copy and paste the ones I have from my html but for some reason the OP ommitted them. I actually tried 2 different ones, "<link href="http://socialadventuring.com/css/socialpolarities.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />" and "<link href="css/socialpolarities.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />", and tried a couple variations of the former. No luck lol.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The problem *was* actually that I needed to put the css file in the home directory, for some strange reason. My path from my html files definitely specified that the css files were in a css directory so I'm not sure if it's something I did wrong or whether the cPanel just sucks. Regardless, it works so I won't mess with it. Now time to copy all of my webfont files into my home directory...this is going to be messy lol.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permission. They should be 755. You can search about permissions on internet. I changed the permissions and it worked fine.